# Compressing files through vroom and piping to pixz

Tags: r, compression, xz, vroom

I would like to write the `mtcars` data.frame to file using compression (`xz` in my case) using the vroom package and `pixz` but I can't get it to write a file. It complains that `pixz` does not exist even though it is installed locally.

According to the vroom vignette (https://vroom.r-lib.org/articles/vroom.html): To compress using a single thread:

```
vroom_write(mtcars, "mtcars.tsv.xz")
```

to compress using a parallel implementation and piping to pixz

```
vroom_write(mtcars, pipe("pixz > mtcars.tsv.xz"))


sh: pixz: command not found
```

Comment: Could be related to `$PATH` variable in your shell environment.

Comment: Thanks Crestor. How would I verify this?

Comment: Try
`shell("which(pixz)")` and 
`shell("pixz")`

Comment: Ah ok, I should say I am on macOS Big Sur, where which pixz produces: /opt/homebrew/bin/pixz

Comment: Then try `vroom_write(mtcars, pipe("opt/homebrew/bin/pixz > mtcars.tsv.xz"))`.

Comment: Hmm that says no such file or directory...

Comment: `pipe("/opt/homebrew/bin/pixz > mtcars.tsv.xz"))` (forgot the inicial "/")

Comment: perfect, thank you! So my understanding is that pixz is not my PATH. Is there a straightforward way of making it "visible"?

Comment: https://osxdaily.com/2014/08/14/add-new-path-to-path-command-line/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the `pixz` command can be found.

You can express the full path ("/opt/homebrew/bin/pixz") or add to the default paths (variable $PATH).
https://osxdaily.com/2014/08/14/add-new-path-to-path-command-line/